# Microsoft Azure Boot Diagnostics Stuck Screen

Tags: azure

When I start my VM my Azure VM boot diagnostics shows up this screen.
How do I interact with this screen?
Need Help
[Azure Boot Diagnostics Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMLVf.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can't interact with the console in Azure virtual machines; if a VM doesn't have (or loses) network connectivity, you have no way to access it. That's (sadly) the single hardest limit of Azure.

---

That said, an Azure VM should not be showing that screen; it looks like a step of the Windows 10 setup, and OS interactive setup is not supposed to happen in an Azure VM. VMs created from marketplace images don't do that, so this must be a custom image, or uploaded VHD, or you did something very unusual to an already-running VM.
How did you get to this point? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This VM was not at all even touched for any purpose, it came popping out for no reason.
Even I'm aware that this kind of scenario is not at all possible, the Azure infrastructure takes care of all boot related issues but I don't know how this thing came out.
I did not even try making any custom image for this machine.

I simply started the VM and this came up.

Comment: That's not a boot error, that's the Windows setup. The only way this can happen on an already-running VM is if someone ran sysprep on it.